# Which data format do I need to decrypt data stored in MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I'm using PHP 7.1, studying encryption/decryption topic. I use this functions to enc/dec (based on PHP's [official doc](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-encrypt.php)):

```
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

function encryptName($plaintext) {
  global $key;
  // $plaintext - string which must be encrypted

  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

  $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
  $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
  $ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
  return $ciphertext;
}

 function decryptName($ciphertext) {
    global $key;
    // $ciphertext - encrypted string

    $c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);

    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);

    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, 
    $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); // | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);

    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
      //echo $original_plaintext."\n";
    }
    echo openssl_error_string();
    return $original_plaintext;  
}
```

When I enc/dec strig "MyTestPhrase" both functions work well. But when I encrypt data and then write it in MySQL table decryption fails with this error code:

```
error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

and my `$original_plaintext` equals `bool(false)`.

I think in this way. AES works with blocks. Decrypted string must be appropriate to block lengt: size of decrypting data must be multiple to 16. If it is not we have to activate PHP option which fullfills it with 0es.

Guess that problem could be with MySQL data format and with encrypted string length, but can't catch it.

Please help me with question posted above.

Comment: Just to rule this out.  You are using the same key that you encrypted with to decrypt after you send to db?

Comment: According to [Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) you need to set your column to type ` VARBINARY` or `BLOB`. Did you do that?

Comment: He should not need to do that. Hes returning it from the encrypt function as base64.  Otherwise good catch.

Comment: @wayneOS, yes, tryed both of them

Comment: @Joseph_J, yes i do

Comment: try to set the column in the db to just text.  You will have to run your code again from ecrypt->insert->retrieve->decrypt to test.

Comment: Done. Unfortunately no result, but error code's digest changed to error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt , and my $original_plaintext is still bool(false)

Comment: your character length the column is long enough? Say 500 characters.  "Text" should have a default size that is adequate, but just asking anyways.  Have you outputted the encrypted value to your browser and compared the db value to see if they are equal.  Please add your insert and select query code to your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172661/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-aysee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my example I created a base64_encoded string using the pseudo_bytes.  That way your key is constant.  You can create your own key but for this ex we will use this one. `LoPCPKd8iDxHvb8mATzhhg==`

Next we will define the key as a constant.  This can be done at the top of your script or in a conf.php file.

Next we will use the constant value anywhere you need the key.

Like so:

```
define("MYKEY_", base64_decode('LoPCPKd8iDxHvb8mATzhhg=='));

function encryptName($plaintext) {

  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

  $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, MYKEY_, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
  $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, MYKEY_, $as_binary=true);
  $ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
  return $ciphertext;
}

 function decryptName($ciphertext) {

    $c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
    $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);

    $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);

    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, MYKEY_,
    $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); // | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, MYKEY_, $as_binary=true);

    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
      //echo $original_plaintext."\n";
    }

    echo openssl_error_string();
    return $original_plaintext;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! The problem was that script was generating a new key with every start. MySQL's data format should be `text` with default length.

Comment: If your doing something like a name or short sentence tinytext (255 max length) should work.  But for larger stuff I would do text.  You may not even be able to set the length of text, but default is just fine.  You could also do varchar and set the length if you are truly concerned about length.